# How do I use a for do loop to sync all channels in an category discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I need a command that will allow me to sync every single channel in a specific category, my idea was to use the for loop but I have no idea how to. How would I come to do this.

Comment: [Don't know the answer? Ask someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68184765/how-do-i-use-a-for-do-loop-to-sync-all-channels-in-an-category-discord-js)

Comment: Jordan, kindly provide more information on the problem you want to solve. In what context are you planning to sync the channels, what are even the channels you want to sync, have you written a for loop before, are you familiar with loops e.t.c

Comment: @Jordan, please go through this tutorial: https://support.glitch.com/t/make-a-pause-in-loop-in-discord-js-when-collecting-answers/28302

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't very familar with for do loops. I ended up doing a channel permission then running a command in the channels I wanted to sync and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work provided your bot has manage channel permissions.  Just provide a category channel as `category` and this will let you sync all child channels:

```js
Client.on('ready', () => {
    // First retrieve your category channel.  Plug in an ID here or provide your own value.
    const category = Client.channels.cache.get('your category ID here');

    // Get the category's children as an array. 
    // Iterating category.children itself was causing problems for me.
    const channels = Array.from( category.children.cache.values() ); 

    for( let channel of channels ){ // for each channel of channels...
        channel.lockPermissions() // sync permissions
        console.log(`Synced ${channel.id}`)
    }
});
```

Reference: [discord.js guides](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#syncing-with-a-category)